# Resonance Audio Reverb Probes + Unity: Not working in build yet working in play-test

Tags: unity-game-engine, resonance-audio

In my project, I have several resonance reverb probes that are working perfectly when I play test inside Unity. However, when I build my scene, the reverb probes wont work in the stand alone app. I have tested builds for Mac and for Android and the reverb probes were not working in either while the rest of the Resonance assets were working just fine.

I then tried building the resonance reverb demo scene to see if perhaps something was going wrong in the building process, and the reverb probes were working well in that build. So I seem to be missing something in my project that is causing my reverbs not to work in builds, yet work perfectly fine in play-test. Any idea what my issue might be?

Comment: Update! 

So I have found a solution to get reverb probes working of standalone build on OS X. The probes were not working because they only work in 64 bit builds (at least that has been the case for me...) so changing the build architecture solved this issue. However, this does not solve my problem for using reverb probes in android builds. Since the probes only work in 64 bit builds and unity only supports up to ARMv7 (32 bit), this means that reverb probes are not an option for mobile VR (oculus Go and Gear VR)... 

Anyone have a similar issue?